# Understanding the structure of a group through its decomposition in normal subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am confused with a basic fact in group theory.

''Given a finite group $G,$ one can find a sequence of subgroups $$G=H_0\lhd H_1\lhd H_2 \cdot \cdot  \cdot \cdot \lhd H_r = \{e\}$$ and such that $H_{k+1}/H_k$ is simple.''
Since one talks about a group in general terms, then the statement must hold also for a simple group,whereby the sequence will be trivial. But in the case $G$ is not simple, by definition it must be solvable and the statement must hold again.

But then we read another statement in algebra books:

''Given the finite group $G,$ it is solvable if one can find a sequence of subgroups $$G=H_0\lhd H_1\lhd H_2 \cdot \cdot  \cdot \cdot \lhd H_r = \{e\}$$ and such that $H_{k+1}/H_k$ is abelian.''

1. To my understanding, since the second statement is more specific than the first one, one would conclude that the abelian groups $H_{k+1}/H_k$ as stated in the second statement are simple (in which case they will be isomorphic to cyclic groups of prime order), something that is not stated in books. At the other hand, since the first statement must be true also for solvable groups, we must conclude that the simple group $H_{k+1}/H_k$ must be abelian in the case of a solvable group.

Can somebody comment on my conclusions and say what is wrong or true. Which statement implies which one, or, are they equivalent in the case of solvable groups ?

2. One also reads in algebra books (I quote here Lang's book) the following: ''such a sequence already gives information about $G$. To get a full knowledge of $G$, one would have to know how these factor groups are pieced together.''

Can somebody explain through an example, what knowledge of $G$ we get through such a sequence and how to proceed to piece the factor groups together.

Many thanks.

Comment: Your point #1 is not quite right, since if $G$ is abelian, then $1 \lhd G$ is a solvable series, and $G$ need not be simple.

Comment: Thanks. An abelian group can be a simple group. Which statement implies which one, or are they equivalent in the case of solvable groups ?

Comment: Right. Simple just means there are no normal subgroups. In an abelian group, all subgroups are normal. So for abelian groups, simple is equivalent to saying there are no nontrivial subgroups.

Comment: Careful: a group not being simple is not equivalent to being “solvable”. Solvable is a term of art, and means that you can find a sequence as above, with each quotient *abelian*, not merely simple.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin. Thanks.  If the first statement is true for all finite groups, why it would not be true for solvable finite groups ? I could agree that the first statement must not imply the second one, but dont understand why the second statement can not imply the first one.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin. Since you are claiming that if a finite group is not simple it must not be solvable, can you give such un example ?

Comment: Take a direct product of a nonabelian simple group with any group you like (such as $A_5 \times A_5$ or $A_5 \times C_2$) and you will get a group that is not simple and not solvable.

Comment: @user249018 That’s rather a combative tone.... $S_5$ is neither simple nor solvable. $A_5\times A_5$ is neither simple nor solvable.

Comment: @user249018: “The first statement is true for all finite groups”. What “first statement”?

Comment: @user249018: I am **not** saying “if a finite group is not simple it must not be solvable.” That would be equivalent to say8ing that if a group is solvable, then it must be simple. What I am pointing out is that your statement, “But in the case $G$ is not simple, then by definition it must be solvable” is incorrect. That would be saying that the only two things a group can be are simple and solvable, and there is no other possibility. But there are certainly finite groups that are neither simple nor solvable.

Comment: Again: are you perhaps using “solvable” at the beginning, before giving the definition, informally? Are you using “solvable” in that paragraph as “can be decomposed into a sequence of subgroups with simple quotients”? Because that seems like a possibility, even though you later give the **definition** of ‘solvable’ which is, as I noted, a term of art.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin. I did not use a combative tone. I just asked a question. Your comments helped me a lot to clarify things which are unfortunately not clearly enough presented in books. I understood two things: for a finite group being not simple does not imply being solvable, and that for a solvable group you can find two composition series, one in which factors are simple and the other one where factors are abelien. These series must not coincide. Correct ?

Comment: Be very careful when you say “must”. In mathematics, it means that it’s a requirement. No, you are not exactly correct. There may be many composition series. Every finite group has *at least one* composition series in which the quotients are simple (these simple groups may or may not be abelian). It could have many different composition series, though the Jordan-Holder Theorem states that the simple groups that occur as quotients of successive terms will be the same (with the same multiplicity, but possibly appearing in different order) in any two such composition series. (Cont)

Comment: Now, separately: a group is said to be “solvable” when there is at least one normal series in which the quotients are abelian. It can be shown that, for a finite group, *if* there is at least one normal series in which the quotients are abelian, then there is a normal series in which the quotients are cyclic of prime order (in which case, you will have a composition series in which all the quotients are simple and abelian). It can also be proven that if you have a finite group, then the group is solvable if and only if in any composition series the simple quotients are all abelian.

Comment: So it is not the case that the series “must not coincide”; if the gorup is finite and solvable, then the composition series with simple quotients will *also* be a witness to the solvability. But not every normal series that is witness to the solvability of the group will have simple quotients. So the series you produce to demonstrate solvability *need not be* (which is different from “must not be”) a composition series with simple quotients.

Comment: (The “combative” part was the phrasing “Since you are claiming X, ca you give an exemple?” I accept that you did not meant it to be combative)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first statement you wrote, that a finite group has a composition series

$$ 1 \lhd G_1 \lhd G_2 \lhd \cdots \lhd G_n = G $$

with all factors simple: this is called the Jordan Holder theorem. This is true for ALL finite groups.

The second type of series, where all the factors are abelian, does not always exist. The group is called "solvable" if such a series exists. But not all finite groups are solvable. Maybe I am misunderstanding your post, but it seems like maybe you are confusing the two notions. They are saying two different things.

As an example, take $G = S_5$, the symmetric group of degree 5. Then a Jordan Holder series is given by

$$ 1 \lhd A_5 \lhd S_5 $$

Here, $A_5$ is the alternating group. The factors are $A_5/1 \cong A_5$ and $S_5/A_5 \cong \Bbb{Z}_2$, which are both simple. However, $A_5$ is NOT abelian, so this is not an example of a solvable series. This illustrates my point that they are two distinct notions. This addresses your point #1 in your post.

To address your question/point #2, let's look at a smaller example: the symmetric group $S_3$. We have the same Jordan-Holder series as above:

$$ 1 \lhd A_3 \lhd S_3 $$

In this smaller case, $A_3 \cong \Bbb{Z}_3$, and this actually is also a solvable series. This is just a coincidence, since the example above shows this does not always happen. In any case, the factor groups are $\Bbb{Z}_3/1 \cong \Bbb{Z}_3$ and $S_3/\Bbb{Z}_3 \cong \Bbb{Z}_2$. Since $A_3 = \Bbb{Z}_3$ is a normal subgroup of $S_3$, and since we can identify the quotient $\Bbb{Z}_2$ with a subgroup of $S_3$ (say generated by one of the transpositions), then you can see that $S_3$ can be realized as the semidirect product $S_3 \cong \Bbb{Z}_3 \rtimes \Bbb{Z}_2$ (I'm leaving out some details...). So the group structure of $S_3$ is determined by the pieces and how they "fit together" (meaning the semidirect product structure).

Comment: Many thanks. In the case of a solvable group, since there exists a composition series of the kind with abelian factors, and since according to the first statement I wrote, factors are simple, does this all means that we have two distinct composition series ? If the two composition series are the same, then necessarily the abelian factors are simple groups. This was meanly my question. Do you agree ?

Comment: That is right. If the composition series are the same, then the factors are both abelian and simple. But they two series do not have to be the same. Even if it is solvable, you could have two different composition series, one with simple factors and one with abelian factors.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It will be great if you give an example of a solvable group with the two composition series: the one following the first statment where the factors are all simple and the second one where the factors are abelian. Ideally if you also provide an example where the two composition series coincide so that the factors are both simple and abelian (I am talking about a solvable group).

Comment: Take an abelian, but not simple group, like $G = \Bbb{Z}_2 \times \Bbb{Z}_2$. Then $1 \lhd G$ is a solvable series, since $G$ is abelian. However, the group is not simple, so this series is NOT of the first type. For that type of series (with simple quotients), you could use $1 \lhd \Bbb{Z}_2 \lhd G$.